# Karma - Instanbul - console.log being counted as test?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I noticed that Karma/Istanbul is marking `console.log()` as covered testcase?
Is there anyway we can make Istanbul to skip `console.log()`?

I could just remove or rename the console.log, but I am interested if there are such options in Istanbul?

Here is an example: [image]

Comment: Coverage will show you which lines of code are execute during the tests and which not. So far I haven't seen a filter in the Istanbul for this use case. You may want to pre-process your files? Just remember that the coverage is a measure to help you improve your testing, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore some statements from coverage report use special formed comments:

https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md